# Is it safe to eat food cooked on a dish on which breaded chicken has been cooked and which wasn't washed?

Tags: baking, chicken

I cooked a frozen breaded chicken steak on a baking tray over 12 hours ago and I have absent-mindedly put something in the oven without washing the tray prior.

Am I in danger of giving myself food poisoning, should I eat this food? (I plan to have it in the oven at 200 Celsius for 30 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe strictly speaking there's a slight risk, but assuming you're a non-pregnant adult with a healthy immune system I would think the chances of any serious food poisoning would be pretty slim.

Comment: The first-order thing to pay attention to here is probably how much debris is actually left on the pan. If there's obvious stuff stuck to it, or if there were some kind of sauce, that'd be a nice home for bacteria. If it's a bit of grease and some dry crumbs that brush off, eh. I assume it's the latter, with a frozen breaded steak.